# Inject specific values into object constructor

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, nestjs, inversifyjs

I have several implementations of an interface and they each need their own configuration injecting into the constructor. My question is if I can somehow hook the dependency injection system in NestJS (presumably Inversify) to inject not just a configuration object, but a specific subset of the configuration object. For example, if `config.ts` looks like this:

```
const config = {
    http: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 3000,
    },
    adapters: {
        disk: {
            path: 'C:\\path\\to\\my\\stuff',
        },
        dropbox: {
            api_key: 'asdfghjkl;',
            api_secret: 'blahblahblahblahblah'
        }
    },
};
```

I want to inject the config in such a way that my disk implementation receives `config.adapters.disk`, my dropbox implementation receives `config.adapters.dropbox` etc. not just `config`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i well understand your request you can use the provider with useValue or useFactory depending what you have to resolve before to be injected.
I let you take a look on that part of the documentation.

As example you can do
{ token: ‘myToken’, useValue: config.property }

And then You just have to inject ‘myToken’ into your constructor.

Also useFactory allow you to process something before returning the value

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm trying to just inject a custom subset of my configuration file into various objects.